# "Lucene.net-2.3.2.1” memory leakages problem

Tags: memory, lucene.net, memory-leaks

I am using Lucene.Net-2.3.2.1 in my project. My project also supporting multithreading environment. Lucene Indexing service is working as Windows Service. **Problem** is when the service is running, it's memory blockage is gradually increasing. So after some hours, it shows a memory of 150 mb in Task Manager where as it start with 13 mb.so it has **a memory increasing** behavior. I identified by dotTrace Profiler that in **Lucene.Net** there are some methods and objects that increased the memory. From Call Tree one of my dotTrace out identify that **Index(), Segment()** related functions hold's memory increased as long as the service perform. So it at a time, it will crash the system.

Please help me how i can recover my application from this memory leakage.

Comment: report your issues on lucene.net dev mailing list and bug tracker in case it's a genuine bug

Answer (score 0):

Increasing memory usage doesn't necessarily implies a memory leak. Memory leaks in .NET are not that common, but there are a few options you should check

- Events. Make sure that all event listeners are detached from the publisher as soon as they are no longer used. Failing to do so will keep the listeners alive as long as the publisher is alive.
- If the code uses any disposable resource that holds handles to native code, be sure to call Dispose on these as soon as they are no longer needed.
- A blocking finalizer will prevent other finalizable objects from being garbage collected, so make sure finalizers don't do any more than they have to (and in many cases they are probably not needed anyway).

If you want to examine which objects are being kept alive as well as why they are not collected, I recommend using WinDbg + Sos.